# Anyway we can set the location of the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Is there an easy way to set the location of a scrollbar all the way to the right. Right now my page is not scrolling but the main content div is. The main content is not all the way to the right. I end up with a smaller scroll bar to the right of the div.

Is there a way to link the body srollbar to my div?

Do I have to make everything fixed and have the entire body to scroll behind?

Comment: Trying to change the standard interface design functionality is a not very good idea I think. Most people can't scroll your div if you'll attach the scroll to the different object.

Comment: I guess im going to have to make it look good then